# How to use boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data, size) to write an int value?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, buffer, boost-asio

I am trying to return an integer to the netcat(tcp) terminal, every time the message sent is Coop25, but this has generated a strange response on the terminal. The response is an  instead of the integer and looks like this:

NETCAT TERMINAL:

Coop25
����

I have tried this function:

```
void tcp::tcp_session::do_write()
{ 
    std::array<int, 1> test{1};
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::mutable_buffer(test.data(), test.size),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
}
```

But when I try using some string this works:

```
std::string ret_mess_check{"blabla"}
const char* mess_to_reply = ret_mess_check.c_str();
do_write(mess_to_reply, strlen(mess_to_reply)); 

void tcp::tcp_session::do_write(const char* reply, std::size_t length)
{ 
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(reply, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
}
```

After @sehe's considerations, I am doing something like this:

in a .hpp file, declaring the mv num_status_{-1};

```
boost::array<int, max_length> num_status_{-1};
```

in a .cpp file, defining the do_write() function, like this:

```
void dac_sim::tcp::tcp_session::do_write()
{ 
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(num_status_),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
}
```

If I replace the member variable from an int to a string, everything works fine. With an int, the "����" still appears instead of -1 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send /buffers/. Your code doesn't compile as given. For starters `test.size` is a pointer-to-member-function. Even if you meant `test.size()` then it would only send 1 byte, because `test.size()` returns 1. Also, you're using `mutable_buffer` when you don't need mutability. I'd write both incantations much simpler and much less error-prone:

```
void tcp::tcp_session::do_write(std::string_view reply) {
    async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(reply),
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                    if (!ec)
                        do_read();
                });
}

void tcp::tcp_session::do_write() {
    async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(test),
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                    if (!ec)
                        do_read();
                });
}
```

You can even combine the two generically:

```
void tcp::tcp_session::do_write(auto const& reply) {
    async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(reply),
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                    if (!ec)
                        do_read();
                });
}
```

And it would work for strings, `array<int, 1>`, `std::vector<myComplicatedPodType>` and even `double[32]` etc. etc.

You can even combine them in a buffer-sequence:

```
async_write(socket_, std::array{asio::buffer(test), asio::buffer(ret_mess_check)},
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec)
                    do_read();
            });
```

### Side Note

Another thing to note about the question code that you MUST NOT use a local variable (like your `test` array) in an asynchronous operation, because it causes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the buffer refers to an object whose lifetime ends before the asynchronous operation completes.

Comment: Thank you so much but I still get this strange "[][][][]" in the netcat terminal. I am trying now your sugestion and I am also declaring test now as a member varible with -1 as initial value.

Comment: boost::array<int, max_length> num_status_{-1};
void tcp::tcp_session::do_write()
{ 
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(num_status_),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
}

Comment: What did you *expect*? An integer is (typically) 4 bytes of binary data. You don't look at binary data using telnet.

Comment: So if you want a text representation of the data, serialize it to a text representation and send **that** as a buffer.

Comment: As an example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/681b93682d19ebb3 or throw a proper serialization library like boost serialization http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ed8302f31b577ff or Boost JSON http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/945fec44bb052d2e at it. Hope that helps